# How can I create a recursive association using GORM?

Tags: mysql, database, go, many-to-many, go-gorm

**Question:** How can I create a recursive association using [GORM](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm)?

**Context:** I have an equipment that can be define manually as well as automatically. I want to associate a manual equipment with the automatically defined one.
So I decided to create a table for this many2many association.

```
CREATE TABLE `equipment` (
  `equipment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `manage_ip` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `equipment`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`equipment_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `unique_equipment` (`model_id`,`manage_ip`);

CREATE TABLE `manual_auto` (
  `manual_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `auto_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `manual_auto`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`manual_id`,`auto_id`),
  ADD KEY `FK_AUTO` (`auto_id`);

ALTER TABLE `manual_auto`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_AUTO` FOREIGN KEY (`auto_id`) REFERENCES `equipment` (`equipment_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_MANUAL` FOREIGN KEY (`manual_id`) REFERENCES `equipment` (`equipment_id`);
```

I know that I can create a many2many association table using `gorm:"many2many:manual_auto"`.
More info on associations with GORM: http://jinzhu.me/gorm/associations.html#belongs-to

```go
type Equipment struct {
    ID        uint
    Ip        string
    Equipment Equipment `gorm:"many2many:manual_auto"`
}
```

Thank you in advance.

**Edit:** More information about the context

I want to have two version of an equipment, one will be created automaticity by fetching another database. Then if any user make a modification about the description of the equipment I want to have 2 version of this equipment, "manual_equipement" and "automatic_equipment".

Comment: Is "recursive" the correct term for this?

Comment: @RickJames Yes absolutely, maybe in English there is another word for this but here is an example: http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=recursive.php

Comment: Oh, in SQL terminology, that is "hierarchical".  And the Manager-Employee example is 1:Many, not many:many.  Notice this single `parent_id` link.  Granted the "matrix" organization leads to the need for many:many.

Comment: Since I don't have a concept of "manual equipment" and "auto equipment", I am having trouble wrapping my head around the problem space.

Comment: @RickJames Edited the question, hope this is more clear

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly, you don't need many-to-many, you need one-to-one. An alternative simpler design would be storing user modifications in separate fields in the same record.

Comment: @Rei Yes you are right about one-to-one association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it's "many", then you need an array/slice:

```
type Equipment struct {
    ID        uint
    Ip        string
    Equipment []Equipment `gorm:"many2many:manual_auto"`
}
```

also names of your manually created schema does not match names from struct. Or you can use [db.AutoMigrate](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/database.html#migration) or define column names in gorm tags:

```
type Equipment struct {
    ID        uint        `gorm:"column:equipment_id"`
    Ip        string      `gorm:"column:manage_ip"`
    Equipment []Equipment `gorm:"many2many:manual_auto"`
}
```

Comment: How can I distinguish manual equipment from automatic ones ? Do I have to add a type in the structure ?